# Can EntryElement be readonly on Monotouch.Dialog?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'm using Monotouch.Dialog for creating a page in my iphone  monotouch application.
The question is that is there a way for making entry element read only in the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inherit EntryElement and override CreateTextField

```
    protected override UITextField CreateTextField(System.Drawing.RectangleF frame)
    {
        var field = base.CreateTextField(frame);
        field.Enabled = false;
        return field;
    }
```